# Создание копии сайта на wordpress

Tags: база-данных, wordpress

Здравствуйте,нужно в общем сделать было копию сайта на WordPress и залить на отдельный домен.

Копию сделал на домен залил,отдельную БД создал и подключил (импортировал в нее старую),но вот вопрос:

1. при попытке зайти в админку, заходит на основной сайт (с которого делал копию)
2. Посоветовали заменить в БД ссылки на старый сайт новыми ссылками, сделал - не помогло.

Так вот,как мне решить данную проблему? что подскажете?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только вчера делал тоже самое )

- Чтобы заходил в админку, достаточно поменять в базе, в таблице Option (как я помню) ссылку на новый сайт.
- Кроме этого, у вашего WordPress-а в конфигах должны быть настройки подключения к новой БД (т.е. вполне возможно, что новый сайт открывает старую БД)
- Если выше не помогло, возможно у вас что-то закешировалось )

Дополнительные проблемы, которые у вас могут возникнуть:

- В статьях ссылка на картинки будут ссылаться на старый сайт;
- Менюшки будут ссылаться на старый сайт;
- Необходимо переставлять плагины и проверять настройки.

Comment: Спасибо. Хотя очень странно,потому что вчера я сделал тоже самое и у меня не работало ничего) 
Ну да ладно ;)

Comment: а вы как делали дубликат сайта? тупо скопировали все папки?

просто я сначало поставил WP, прогнал через установщик, загнал все файлы, которых не было, импортировал БД, поменял ссылки в БД, и в админке позже поменял ссылки.

т.е. я думаю, у вас проблема в настройках подключения к БД )

Comment: Поставил вп,скопировал туда все папочки,импортировал бд :)

ЗЫ Проблема решена) все успешно заработало))